# Why does Next.js 13 ESLint --fix flag not fix the ESLint warnings and errors?

Tags: next.js, eslint, next.js13, prettier

So below is the `package.json` file, and from what I've seen on other code bases and tutorials this should work, i.e. running `npm run lint:fix` should fix the errors and warnings I get when I run `npm run lint`. However `npm run lint:fix` does nothing when I run it, but simply returns the errors and warnings I get from `npm run lint` as well.

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "lint:fix": "next lint --fix",
    "format": "prettier --check --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "format:fix": "prettier --write --ignore-path .gitignore ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "14.0.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.5.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^3"
  }
}
```

And this is my `.eslintrc.json` file:

```js
{
  "extends": ["next", "next/core-web-vitals", "prettier"]
}
```

and `.prettierrc.json` file:

```js
{
  "plugins": ["prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"]
}
```

What could be the problem? Thank you